# How to include "www." in Google Search listing?

Tags: html, url, google-search

Do you know how to make sure a website listing in Google search shows the "www." in front of the URL?

My site is simply appearing without the "www." in the URL.

I tried a 301 redirect but after a couple of months it still didn't change.

Its probably something simple but I don't know.

Thank you

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ZO0.png)

Comment: Why do you want "www"? It's a bit 1990s.

Comment: Yeah I know haha I just prefer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to redirecting all you're URLs to `www` (and making sure the URLS work), you should create a sitemap and then submit it to Google WMT. It will take a while, but they will eventually change to `www`

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help Samuel!